# Tracking podcasts on website, app, and XML feed

Tags: analytics, tracking, podcast

I have an XML/RSS podcast feed that links to all of my organization's podcasts. The mp3 files themselves are stored on our FTP, which the XML feed links to.

I'd like to start tracking how many times a podcast is getting played/downloaded. The mp3 files are played in one of three ways:

1) Through our website, via links that go directly to the mp3 file.

2) Through our app, in its podcast section. The app allows you to play any our podcasts, but I'm not sure if playing the podcasts on the app is trackable.

3) Through downloads/plays of our podcasts from the XML feed.

I admittedly don't understand how this works very well. Is there a way to track plays for all of these podcasts through one service? I've looked at Feedburner and Blubrry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to track the downloads of your podcast episodes (e.g., mp3 files on your server) is using a software for graphical log analysis, such as [Awstats](http://www.awstats.org/). In many cases it comes as a pre-installed package in your web server and, if you have a hosting provider, it will be probably available to the customers via the Control Panel.

In case you don't have access neither to the server logs nor to log analysis tools, you can follow the official Technical Specifications for podcasts by Apple, where you'll find instructions to implement [alternative ways to track the number of times that each episode has been downloaded](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html#tracking) (see section "Tracking Usage").

Finally, you could also give a look to third-party services such as [Podtrac](http://podtrac.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I ended up going with your last suggestion -- a third-party service, Libsyn (http://libsyn.com). They offer comprehensive stats and are easy to integrate.